# How does a single variable store multiple values?

Tags: c++

I recently began learning programming using C++, and came across this problem called, 'Life, the Universe, and Everything'. I found a solution from Google, and modified it a bit to understand it better.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    int number;
    while(1){
        cin >> number;
        if(number==42)
            break;
        cout << number << " ";
    }
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

An output from the above program was:

```
1 2 88 42 99
1 2 88
```

Here I do not understand how the variable `number` stores multiple values from the input stream, and keeps storing values until I press *Return*. As far as I knew, a variable can only store a single value of it's corresponding data-type.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`int num;` stores only one number at a time.

`cin >> number` replaces the stored number with the next number from input.

Comment: In the displayed test case, all the inputs are taken together, and only then is the output shown. Which clearly means that the entire process happened in one iteration of the loop. So, do the replaced numbers get stored in the output stream? They need to be stored somewhere, because clearly the output stream is able to access all the values, which would not be possible if the previous values were replaced by newer ones without storing them somewhere.

Comment: In addition the value of the variable is printed in _every_ iteration of the loop. Probably that's what causes the confusion here. It seems like a vector of numbers is printed.

Comment: @elementalneil Partially wrong. The input stream "waits" until you press enter. Then it receives the whole line of input (it's buffered). Then It reads _one_ number, stores it in `number`, prints this number and starts the loop over again, reading the next number from the buffer. And so on, until 42 is encountered.

Comment: @elementalneil The console input is *line-buffered*. When you reach `cin >> number;` for the first time, there is no number in the input yet, so the program waits until you input something *and press enter*. `1 2 88 42 99` is stored in the input stream as a string. `cin >> number` reads numbers one by one from this string.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Apologies if I come across as a newbie(I am). Each iteration would involve a single input and then a single output. Here there are 5 inputs at the same time, and then 3 outputs.

Comment: @elementalneil Being a newbie is ok. :) *"Each iteration would involve a single input and then a single output"* That's what happens. Try typing one number per line, and you'll get the behavior you expect. `cin >> number;` lets you input one line, and if it has more than one number, the excess numbers as stored in the input stream (as a string), and when you reach `cin >> number;` again, it reads the next number from that string. Only when that string is empty, it will pause again and wait for more input.

Comment: @churill So, the input is buffered. That really clears it up. Thanks.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat That really clears it up, thanks a ton.

Answer (score 2):

This is not the output:

```
1 2 88 42 99
1 2 88
```

The first line is your input, and the second line is the output. Each loop iteration reads one number from the input stream during `cin >> number`, and the rest of the input stream is left unread until the next loop round. So the values are stored in the input stream, not in `number`.

Comment: I was thinking for quite a while, why the program would output `42` at any point until I saw this answer. Thanks